# Show that $x^2$ $= y^2$ iff $x=y$ or $x=-y$ for any $x$ and $y$ in an integral domain R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Things I know:

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $R$.

There is a multiplicative identity $1 \in R$; commutative $\times$

No zero divisors: $xy=0$ $\implies$ $x=0$ or $y=0$.

By algebra; $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ and if we allow $(x+y)(x-y)=0$, we obtain $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

How can I proceed?

Comment: You have a typo. It should be $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: That proves the "only if" part. The direct implication should be straightforward.

Comment: You want your domain to be commutative.

Comment: @dxiv where should I look for the "if" part?

Comment: Just show that if $x=\pm y$ then $x^2=y^2$.

Comment: @dxiv  if we consider two cases, the first case being $x=y$ and the second $x=-y$, I have shown $y^2 = y^2$. Did you mean this when you stated "straightforward implication?"

Comment: Or you can reuse the same argument as above, just going backwards: if $x=-y$ (for example) then $x+y=0$ therefore $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x, y \in R$.

$x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)=0$.

Either $x+y=0$ or $x-y=0\implies x=±y$.

If $x=±y$, then $x^2=y^2$.

Case 1: $x=y \implies (y)^2 = y^2$ (true).

Case 2: $x=-y \implies (-y)^2 = y^2$ (true).